# Correspondency model - table on CodeIgniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter

If I had a table called URL_PETICIO, how the model should be called on CodeIgniter2 ?

I don't  know how to set the tablename where the model has to point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check documentation how to create model and how to use it in controller:

https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/models.html

Here is the code where you can get records from a database table:

```
$query = $this->db->get('your_table_name', 10);
return $query->result();
```

In the above code `your_table_name` is the table and `10` means is `limit 10` it will get the only `10` records from database

Comment: I did check it befor ask  but I didn't see how is the convention between model name and table name or how is setted the table in the model